# How can I stream a video file to a Google TV's Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, vlc, google-tv, logitech

I have attempted to setup a local streaming media server using VLC w/ a '.asx' file and an '' tag in an html file served by a local HTTP Server (Please see: http://wiki.videolan.org/Simple_Stream_VLC_to_Website ) on the same machine (as VLC). VLC is streaming the local file(s) perfectly (e.g. if I open the HTTP address from any web browser on a PC in the local network, including Chrome, it works flawlessly). However, I am looking for a way to stream content from the server and view it on a Google TV (i.e. Logitech Revu) using the built-in Chrome browser application, hence I am using http/html. I have been to websites that stream video (via flash?) within the browser. I would like to replicate this with my own local content. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am also hoping to create a formidable tutorial from any data gathered. Thank you.

p.s. I am open to server-side workarounds as my primary goal is to stream video inside a webpage on the Google TV's native Chrome app.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into HLS. Essentially you need a web catcher. 
http://4pcbr.com/topic/a_story_about_hls_video_handling and 
http://www.jasonshah.com/http-live-streaming-and-android/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming